# React Native screen trying to export function

Tags: react-native

New to React (and Native), I'm trying to modify [this working Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Authentication%20flows%20%C2%B7%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%405.0.4%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fauth-flow.js). I'm trying to move the `SignInScreen` to its own file and call it from the default App file, here is my SignInScreen file where the error is happening:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const context = React.createContext();

export function SignInScreen() {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  console.log(context);

  const {signIn} = React.useContext(context); //blows up here

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={setUsername}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button title="Sign in" onPress={() => signIn({ username, password })} />

    </View>
  );
}
```

Called via `<Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen}>`

I'm getting an error:

> Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined at SignInScreen

I'm assuming this just an encapsulation (or syntax or scope) issue I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an implementation of the `signIn` function. You can either do this when you call `createContext` or passing it down as the `Provider` value for that context (assuming you have one, otherwise that's another problem).

```js
const context = createContext({
    signIn : ({ username, password }) => {
        console.log(username, password);
    }
});
```

I suggest you read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) a little bit.

Comment: Thanks, I've been knee deep in React Native since posting the question, and now I have to laugh at my own question.